# Delete Table Row From Userform

Tags: excel, vba

I have made a userform for deleting a row of data. Is it possible when i delete a row of data, the only row affected is the table row, while the same row outside the table is not deleted?

For example, if want to remove Bill, test1, and 345, is it possible to make the data1 still remain there and not removed?

[image: Example]

I have this code but it delete the entire row, any idea how to modify this?

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
Dim profile_id As String
profile_id = ComboBox9.value
Lastrow = Sheets("Profile").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To Lastrow
If Sheets("Profile").Cells(i, 1).value = profile_id Then
Sheets("Profile").Rows(i).Delete
Unload Me
MsgBox "Your data has been deleted", vbOKOnly, "Successful"
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You're not referencing a Table object, only the Worksheet. If you have a userform with data populated from the Table, then my solution below will suffice. If it does not, please post more details so we can assist you. At the very least, tell us the Table name and how you're populating the userform, types of controls, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will not affect other content on the sheet

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListRows(3).Delete
```

Comment: So i dont need to insert the table name?

Comment: You should definitely use the tablename if you have >1 table on the sheet, and probably it's good practice to use it just in case you add another table later.  The code I posted is just an example: since you didn't post any code I can't "fit it in" with your existing setup.

Comment: This isn't doing what the OP asked, as it's removing a Table row completely, not just the list in the userform. Also, everything is hard-coded. ? Not a good solution.

Comment: Meh, up to you. I did.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-posted: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/remove-table-row-from-userform.1132450/

Answering for posterity. If you load the data in your userform, I'm assuming into a ListBox control, as an array and not sourced directly to the Table data, then yes you can do that. You'd basically loop through your listbox data (array), find any selected item, and remove it with the RemoveItem method. Here is an example:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Index As Long
    Dim RemoveRow As Long
    Dim Values As Variant

    Values = Me.ListBox1.List
    RemoveRow = -1

    For Index = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListBox1.Selected(Index) Then
            RemoveRow = Index
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Index

    If RemoveRow = -1 Then Exit Sub
    Me.ListBox1.RemoveItem RemoveRow

End Sub
```

If you wanted to actually remove the Table row, and not in the userform only first, you would replace this line:

```
Me.ListBox1.RemoveItem RemoveRow
```

With these lines:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Profile").ListObjects("Table1").ListRows(RemoveRow + 1).Delete
Me.ListBox1.List = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Profile").ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.Value
```

Again, changing the sheet/Table names to suit.

Comment: Hello, could you please help me in which line should i modify my code?